# Evaluate $ \int \frac{3x+1}{x^2+4x+4}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

$$ 
\int \frac{3x+1}{x^2+4x+4}dx
$$

How can I solve this integral? I can't find any way that lead to $$\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}$$

I tried with WolframAlpha but the explanation wasn't very intuitive this time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you see that $x^{2}+4x+4=(x+2)^{2}$. Now you can use substitution. Take $u=x+2$ then $du=dx$. this means that you can rewrite the integral as following:
\begin{align}
\int\frac{3x+1}{x^{2}+4x+4}dx&=\int\frac{3x+1}{(x+2)^{2}}dx\\
&=\int\frac{3(u-2)+1}{u^{2}}du\\
&=\int\frac{3u-5}{u^{2}}du\\
&=\int\frac{3u}{u^{2}}du-\int\frac{5}{u^{2}}du\\
&=\int\frac{3}{u}du-\int\frac{5}{u^{2}}du\\
&=3\ln(u)+\frac{5}{u}+C
\end{align}

I hope I used enough little steps to guide you trough your excercise. If I didn't calculate wrong this must be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator is $(x+2)^2$, so the integrand is $\frac{3(x+2)-5}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{3}{x+2}-\frac{5}{(x+2)^2}$, which I leave you to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom factorises into $(x + 2)^2$ and so you can substitute $z = x + 2$.

It then becomes an integral in $(a z + b) / z^2$ which should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$3x+1=\frac32(2x+4)-5$$